# css columns add extra space at bottom

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I've got css columns in effect (in wp). I'm getting extra space below the content. The height of the extra space matches that of the paragraph that has been moved over to the 2nd column, as if the browser is thinking that paragraph is not in a 2nd column. This is creating an unwanted scrollbar. It's something dumb but I can't figure it out. Help?

```
body.single article.post .entry-content {
 border-top: 1px solid #666;
 padding-top: 20px;
 -moz-columns: 2 400px; /* Firefox */
 -moz-column-gap: 3em;
 -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #666;
 -moz-column-fill: balance;
 -webkit-columns: 2 400px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-column-gap: 3em;
 -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #666;
 columns: 2 400px;
 column-gap: 3em;
 column-rule: 1px solid #666;
 column-fill: balance;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 text-align: justify;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: .9em;
 text-indent: 2em;
}
```

[Demo page](http://worldofcoracle.com/lorem-ipsum/)

[image: Screenshot of extra space]

Comment: So far have also tried display inline-block, overflow, margin 0, etc on the div and the p tags inside it with no luck

Comment: And it appears to happen in Safari only. Not Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Looks fine in Chromium ... Is that Safari you are using there in that screenshot? Well we all know that's the new IE, right?

Comment: Now that I simplified it for the lorem ipsum demo page it's working. I'll update if I can figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Although if you hover over the main text inside the <p> tag in an inspector you can still see it's "true" height which includes the content moved to the 2nd column.